# How to extract all row numbers containing specific string from specific column of Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I want to visualise a DataFrame I have created from a CSV-file with pandas for a school assignment. The DataFrame contains data about sentences from two different book chapters. I would like to extract data from one specific book chapter and create two new separate DataFrames. I'm therefore trying to access all rows containing "1" (as in chapter 1) of column "chapter". 
This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
    length                                          sentences  chapter  ranking
0       99  The word "house" is not a linguistic fact if b...        1        1
1      201  In an age when the study of antiquity attracte...        2        1
2       88  This can only mean that the sounds of speech a...        1        2
3      145  If you consider that whatever view we take of ...        2        2
4       75  If the involuntary cry of pain which is conven...        1        3
5      136  For it is evident we observe no footsteps in t...        2        3
6       71  The auditory centers alone may be excited; or ...        1        4
7      118  Man had studied every part of nature the miner...        2        4
8       68  The auditory symbolism may be replaced point f...        1        5
9      116  It has absorbed the thoughts of men who after ...        2        5
10      68  These symbols are in the first instance audito...        1        6
11      93  The dimensions of the science of language are ...        2        6
12      68  Naturally the particular points or clusters of...        1        7
13      91  The astronomer retains these and many other na...        2        7
14      66  It is even conceivable if not exactly likely t...        1        8
15      92  Lord Monboddo for instance admits that as yet ...        2        8
16      65  As such they may be considered an integral por...        1        9
17      89  It is counted as a science by so sound and sob...        2        9
18      63  If language can be said to be definitely "loca...        1       10
19      86  If with all these difficulties and drawbacks I...        2       10
```

I have tried selecting the wanted rows using this code and assigning them to a new variable (chapter1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('task1.csv')

chapter1 = df[df.chapter == '1']
```

I would like to create a new dataframe of these rows. I get the ERROR message:
elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

How do I solve this ERROR?

Thankful for all help

Comment: `chapter1 = df[df.chapter == '1'].copy()`

Comment: This didn't work. I get the same error message

Comment: I missed the `containing` part. Is the `chapter` column list-like valued?

Comment: Try with `chapter1 = df[df['chapter'].str.contains('1')]` If this does not work, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58662941/edit) your post and add a sample of your dataframe, so we can understand how the data looks like. Otherwise is like shooting in the dark.

Comment: That code produced error message ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!```. I have now added the dataframe, so things become clearer.
@QuangHoang this is what the dataframe and ```chapter``` column looks like.

Comment: Try `chapter1 = df.loc[df['chapter'] == 1]`

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a pretty good example of why you should always check your dtypes after importing data to create a dataframe.  Use `df.info()`